how to Use OV7670 Camera Module With STM32F46-DISCOVERY board?
I have a STM32F746 discovery board that needs to be connected to ov7670 camera module, i searched online but i couldn't find any document or solution related to it. Can anybody help me out?

Same way as you interface literally any IC with a microcontroller. You open the IC's datasheet/documentation, and it tells you what protocols it supports, what commands and functions are available to you. If you're lucky, there is a library somewhere, but in general there are way too many combinations of ICs and MCUs, so if there is no library, it will be you who will have to implement all the necessary commands to operate the IC. If this doesn't answer your question, then you will have to specify what kind of answer you're looking for (what do you want to see in it).
